# How can I run a shell script as a daemon under Redhat?

Tags: shell-script, rhel, init-script

I've got a shell script, which is essentially a one liner with some logging, which I'm trying to run this from an init script. I'm using the `daemon` function inside of `/etc/init.d/functions` to run it, as Redhat does not appear to have `start-stop-daemon` available. When I call the init script (`/etc/init.d/script start`) it stays in the foreground, rather than completing and leaving the process running. What's the proper way for me to get this script daemonized?

Script to be run:

```
# conf file where variables are defined
. /etc/script.conf

echo "Starting..." | logger -i
echo "Monitoring $LOG_LOCATION." | logger -i
echo "Sending to $MONITOR_HOST:$MONITOR_PORT." | logger -i

tail -n 1 -F $LOG_LOCATION |
grep WARN --line-buffered  |
/usr/bin/nc -vv $MONITOR_HOST $MONITOR_PORT 2>&1 |
logger -i
```

init script:

```
#!/bin/bash


# Source Defaults
. /etc/default/script

# Source init functions
. /etc/init.d/functions

prog=/usr/local/bin/script.sh

[ -f /etc/script.conf ] || exit 1

RETVAL=0

start()
{
    # Quit if disabled
    if ! $ENABLED; then
            echo "Service Disabled in /etc/default/script"
            exit 1
    fi

    echo "Starting $prog"

    daemon $prog

    RETVAL=$?

    return $RETVAL
}

stop ()
{
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    killproc $prog

    RETVAL=$?

    return $RETVAL
}

reload()
{
    echo "Reload command is not implemented for this service."
    return $RETVAL
}

restart()
{
    stop
    start
}

condrestart()
{
    echo "Not Implemented."
}

# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    status)
        status $prog
        ;;
    restart)
        restart
        ;;
    reload)
        reload
        ;;
    condrestart)
        condrestart
        ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|condrestart|reload}"
        RETVAL=1
esac
```

Last ~20 lines of execution with bash -vx:

```
+ case "$1" in
+ start
+ true
+ echo 'Starting /usr/local/bin/script.sh'
Starting /usr/local/bin/script.sh
+ daemon /usr/local/bin/script.sh
+ local gotbase= force=
+ local base= user= nice= bg= pid=
+ nicelevel=0
+ '[' /usr/local/bin/script.sh '!=' /usr/local/bin/script.sh ']'
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ base=script.sh
+ '[' -f /var/run/script.sh.pid ']'
+ '[' -n '' -a -z '' ']'
+ ulimit -S -c 0
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' color = verbose -a -z '' ']'
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ initlog -q -c /usr/local/bin/script.sh
```

Comment: It seems useful to me that you run that script through `bash -vx ...` and post the last lines so that we can see what stays in the foreground.

Comment: Don't bother getting the usage of this right and go with [`daemon`](http://libslack.org/daemon/), there's [a RPM package](http://libslack.org/daemon/#download), too.  Btw, there're many log monitoring tools out there ([start here](https://github.com/monitoringsucks/tool-repos)).

Comment: Hauke, do you mean using a first line of `#!/bin/bash -vx`? I tried doing this, but it didn't produce the same output from the init script as it does if I run the shell script directly.

Comment: @bshacklett you can examine any init script's (any shell script's actually) function by running it explicitly with `bash -vx`, ie. `bash -vx /etc/init.d/script start`.

Comment: It appears to be stopping at + initlog -q -c /usr/local/bin/script.sh

Comment: @sr_ I'm sorry, but I'm having a bit of trouble weeding through all of those tools. Are there any specific log monitoring tools you would recommend? Also, I'm doing my best to make as few changes on the system to be monitored as possible, because of the vendor support model and how they've customized it.

Comment: @bshacklett W.r.t logs, I'd have a closer look at [logstash](http://logstash.net/).  The store can be fed logs directly from Log4j, but the logstash agent can also monitor log files

Comment: @sr_ Thanks. I've been meaning to get looking into logstash. I'll have to start digging into it in a bit more depth now.

Comment: @bshacklett: I just stumbled upon [dendrite](https://github.com/onemorecloud/dendrite), fitting into a related niche, could be interesting here.

Comment: As @sr_ points, I think that daemon binary is just what you is looking for. An really easy and a lot of configurable way to daemonize anything.

Comment: I suspect you're right, erm3nda. Unfortunately, there was a requirement which prevented that binary from being installed. 3rd party software can be frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a script at http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/190279-daemon-etc-init-d-functions-does-not-return-launching-process.html#post897522 which I was able to modify to suit my needs. It manually tracks the PID and creates a PID file using `pidof`. I ended up having to modify this to use `pgrep` as `pidof` was unable to see the PID of my script. After that modification, it worked fine. *Note, pgrep seems to only work if the full script name is under 15 characters long

Here's what I ended up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# 
#
# Start on runlevels 3, 4 and 5. Start late, kill early.
# chkconfig: 345 95 05
#
#
#!/bin/bash

# absolute path to executable binary
progpath='/usr/local/bin/script.sh'

# arguments to script
opts=''

# binary program name
prog=$(basename $progpath)

# pid file
pidfile="/var/run/${prog}.pid"

# make sure full path to executable binary is found
! [ -x $progpath ] && echo "$progpath: executable not found" && exit 1

eval_cmd() {
  local rc=$1
  if [ $rc -eq 0 ]; then
    echo '[  OK  ]'
  else
    echo '[FAILED]'
  fi
  return $rc
}

start() {
  # see if running
  local pids=$(pgrep $prog)

  if [ -n "$pids" ]; then
    echo "$prog (pid $pids) is already running"
    return 0
  fi
  printf "%-50s%s" "Starting $prog: " ''
  $progpath $opts &

  # save pid to file if you want
  echo $! > $pidfile

  # check again if running
  pgrep $prog >/dev/null 2>&1
  eval_cmd $?
}

stop() {
  # see if running
  local pids=$(pgrep $prog)

  if [ -z "$pids" ]; then
    echo "$prog not running"
    return 0
  fi
  printf "%-50s%s" "Stopping $prog: " ''
  rm -f $pidfile
  kill -9 $pids
  eval_cmd $?
}

status() {
  # see if running
  local pids=$(pgrep $prog)

  if [ -n "$pids" ]; then
    echo "$prog (pid $pids) is running"
  else
    echo "$prog is stopped"
  fi
}

case $1 in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  status)
    status
    ;;
  restart)
    stop
    sleep 1
    start
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
    exit 1
esac

exit $?
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Redhat but `daemon $prog &` looks strange to me. If there is already a function for daemonizing why should it be necessary (and useful) to put this function itself in the background? Thus try without the `&`.

Comment: It's not wrong.  `/etc/init.d/functions` defines a `daemon` function that expects its argument to daemonize itself, it only takes care of things like changing the user, setting ulimits, checking (not creating!) a pidfile...  The best usage of this `daemon` function is to replace it with [libslack's `daemon`](http://libslack.org/daemon/) ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, the & was there at one point when I was troubleshooting. I did not mean to include it in this post.